# What can I do to make Windows 10 recognize the battery (again)?

Tags: windows-10, battery, ubuntu-14.04, hardware-detection

I bought a used laptop (Acer Aspire V5-553G). Everything was fine until yesterday. Windows 10 Professional does not recognize the battery anymore.

- **The Battery charges and functions normally otherwise.**
- When I boot Ubuntu (from USB stick) the battery status is shown. So, my guess is that it is something software related.
- BIOS is up-to-date

I already tried unsuccessfully:

- draining the battery, charging and starting Windows
- uninstalling/Reinstalling the battery in the device manager

What can I do to make Windows recognize the battery again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ubuntu detected the battery, I knew that it had to be a software problem.

However, the only thing that actually worked was a hardware fix:

- shut it down
- remove battery
- boot Windows with AC adapter connected
- uninstall the battery from the device manager
- shut it down
- put battery back in (fully charged), remove AC adapter
- boot Windows
- battery should be detected again